# getting either 1 or -1

Tags: r, function

I want to get from the user either -1 or 1, but the attached function allows the user to input any value. How can it be modified?

```
readB.Y<-function(){ 
#B.Y is a storage variable that will be used later
B.Y<-readline(prompt = "ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:")
# if the input is not integer, ask again for integer input
if(!grepl("^[0-9]+$",B.Y)){
    if(B.Y!=-1|BY!=1)
    return(readB.Y())
}
# to ensure the input is integer
return(as.integer(B.Y))
}
BY<-readB.Y()
```

Thank you.

Comment: suppress `if(B.Y!=-1|BY!=1)` and change your condition to `(!grepl("^-?[0-9]+$",B.Y)) | (!(B.Y %in% c(-1, 1)))` it will test everything at once.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your condition to allow negative numbers and exclude numbers that are different from -1 and 1:

```
readB.Y <- function(){ 
#B.Y is a storage variable that will be used later
B.Y<-readline(prompt = "ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:")
# if the input is not integer, ask again for integer input
if((!grepl("^-?[0-9]+$",B.Y)) | (!(B.Y %in% c(-1, 1)))){ # -? means that it can or not have a minus sign
   return(readB.Y())
} else {
# to ensure the input is integer
return(as.integer(B.Y))
}
}
```

You can further simplify your condition to

```
readB.Y <- function(){ 
#B.Y is a storage variable that will be used later
B.Y<-readline(prompt = "ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:")
# if the input is not integer, ask again for integer input
if(!grepl("^-?1$", B.Y)){ # what is enter can only be 1 or -1
   return(readB.Y())
} else {
# to ensure the input is integer
return(as.integer(B.Y))
}
}
```

**Examples:**

```
BY<-readB.Y()
#ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:99
#ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:2
#ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:-1
BY<-readB.Y()
#ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:6
#ENTER THE NUMBER OF B.Y:1
```